# RasPi 4B/Waveshare 7" (C) touch not working after boot

Tags: raspbian, usb, touchscreen, lcd

I'm using a RasPi 4B with a HiFiBerry Amp2 "on top" and a Waveshare 7" (C) touch LCD Rev 2.1.

The setup is intended to become my "web radio" using Volumio or Kodi.

I'm having the problem on each of the following:

- LibreELEC,
- OSMC and
- the latest Raspian

The problem is that the touch function of the LCD doesn't work after boot.  Resetting the USB bus via

```
echo "0" | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.4\:1.0/authorized
echo "1" | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.4\:1.0/authorized
```

doesn't help.

Only after un- and replugging the USB cable does the touch screen come alive.

I'm including the (Raspian) output of

```
dmesg | grep -i usb
```

below, it shows the effect of the `echo "0" | sudo tee ...` commands at 31.711333 (inserted manually) and the un-/replugging action starting at 95.183393.

The touch screen doesn't work at the 31.711333 point, but works just after 98.256108.

How do I get the touch screen to work at boot? Or how can I reset it via software shortly after boot?

```
[    0.164701] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.164754] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.164837] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.165184] usb_phy_generic phy: supply vcc not found, using dummy regulator
[    0.165379] usb_phy_generic phy: dummy supplies not allowed for exclusive requests
[    1.348498] usbcore: registered new interface driver r8152
[    1.348561] usbcore: registered new interface driver lan78xx
[    1.348636] usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc95xx
[    1.350398] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    1.351893] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    1.351916] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: Host supports USB 3.0 SuperSpeed
[    1.352278] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.15
[    1.352298] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.352312] usb usb1: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.352325] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 5.15.76-v8+ xhci-hcd
[    1.352338] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:01:00.0
[    1.353080] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.354195] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 5.15
[    1.354216] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.354231] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.354244] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 5.15.76-v8+ xhci-hcd
[    1.354257] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:01:00.0
[    1.354912] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.357568] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[    1.357672] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    1.368003] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    1.368016] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    1.615275] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    1.765952] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=3431, bcdDevice= 4.21
[    1.766001] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[    1.766027] usb 1-1: Product: USB2.0 Hub
[    1.768228] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.063325] usb 1-1.4: new full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    2.170474] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=0eef, idProduct=0005, bcdDevice= 2.00
[    2.170513] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    2.170528] usb 1-1.4: Product: By ZH851
[    2.170542] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: BYZHYYZHY
[    2.170555] usb 1-1.4: SerialNumber: `\x12P357v\x112033
[    2.184609] input: BYZHYYZHY By ZH851 Mouse as /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/0003:0EEF:0005.0001/input/input0
[    2.185112] input: BYZHYYZHY By ZH851 Touchscreen as /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/0003:0EEF:0005.0001/input/input1
[    2.185836] hid-generic 0003:0EEF:0005.0001: input,hiddev96,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse     [BYZHYYZHY By ZH851] on usb-0000:01:00.0-1.4/input0
[    5.528200] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[    6.482589] input: BYZHYYZHY By ZH851 as /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/0003:0EEF:0005.0001/input/input3
[    6.655637] hid-multitouch 0003:0EEF:0005.0001: input,hiddev96,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse     [BYZHYYZHY By ZH851] on usb-0000:01:00.0-1.4/input0
[   31.711333] cam-dummy-reg: disabling
[   95.183393] usb 1-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 3
[   95.412401] usb 1-1.4: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[   95.700659] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[   95.915494] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=0eef, idProduct=0005, bcdDevice= 2.00
[   95.915523] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[   95.915540] usb 1-1.4: Product: By ZH851
[   95.915553] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: BYZHYYZHY
[   95.915566] usb 1-1.4: SerialNumber: `\x12P357v\x112033
[   95.932277] input: BYZHYYZHY By ZH851 as /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/0003:0EEF:0005.0002/input/input5
[   95.936424] hid-multitouch 0003:0EEF:0005.0002: input,hiddev96,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse     [BYZHYYZHY By ZH851] on usb-0000:01:00.0-1.4/input0
[   96.207367] usb 1-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 4
[   98.136375] usb 1-1.4: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[   98.243448] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=0eef, idProduct=0005, bcdDevice= 2.00
[   98.243463] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[   98.243470] usb 1-1.4: Product: By ZH851
[   98.243475] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: BYZHYYZHY
[   98.243481] usb 1-1.4: SerialNumber: `\x12P357v\x112033
[   98.255715] input: BYZHYYZHY By ZH851 as /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/0003:0EEF:0005.0003/input/input7
[   98.256108] hid-multitouch 0003:0EEF:0005.0003: input,hiddev96,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse     [BYZHYYZHY By ZH851] on usb-0000:01:00.0-1.4/input0
```

**Update 1:** I'm getting the same behaviour on an Odroid-N2+.

**Update 2:** Same problem when connecting to my linux laptop (via docking station)

Comment: have you tried without the HiFiBerry?

Comment: @JaromandaX no, but with an Odroid-N2+. Same problem. :(

Comment: not sure how that is relevant

Answer (score 0):

**Update 3:** Bought a new LCD of the same kind, which now works fine.  Most likely, the old LCD was simply broken, as its touchscreen should have worked up front.